# How to change the default Alamofire cache time if possible?

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am currently making a call to an API using [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) and I want the response to be cached for reuse (which [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) provides by default) BUT only for an hour maximum and then it should make another call to the API after the said time period.

```
AF.request("someUrl...")
  .validate().responseJSON { response in
       switch response.result {
             case .success:
                // some logic
             case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
       }
}
```

Everything seems good but I cannot find a way to know or alter the cache time using [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire).

could anyone suggest how I can alter the cache time and integrate it to the above code?

Thanks in advance, appreciated for the time & help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle it by yourself, Means you need to track the time of last cached image & if previous request was older than your time limit then remove a cached response before firing that request again like:

```
let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "someUrl...")!)

URLCache.shared.removeCachedResponse(for: urlRequest) // remove older cache

// now request again, with your method.

AF.request("someUrl...")
.validate().responseJSON { response in
   switch response.result {
         case .success:
            // some logic
         case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
   }
}
```